# Questions aren't sorted by frequency

Tags: support, sorting, questions

So I choose "questions" > "frequent", but they aren't sorted by frequency.
This is the case on both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.

On MSO, 532 views > 2 kviews > 671 views

Comment: What questions do you see in the list? For me, it shows what I'd expect.

Comment: @icktoofay 532 views > 2 kviews > 671 views

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the frequent tab is for. Your comment suggests you think it's sorted by views, but that's not the case. Rather, it sorts by number of questions closed as a duplicate of it. If a question is asked many times and is closed as a duplicate, then indeed, that question is now a ‘frequent[ly asked]’ question.

**See also:** [What's the 'Frequent' sort function?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172726/whats-the-frequent-sort-function)